# What, exactly, is a BLE connected device on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

The `CBCentralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals` method says it gets "the list of the peripherals currently connected to the system." The definition of system is a bit ambiguous here.

Does this mean I get a list of peripherals connected to my app, or a list of peripherals connected to *any* app?

If I can get peripherals connected to another app, does this also mean multiple apps can connect to the same peripheral?

Can this only happen if the app is in the foreground, or do I need to allow for the possibility that a background app is sending commands to a peripheral I think my app owns?

Comment: Very good question. I couldn't agree more on the lack of documentation from Apple on this framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BLE 4.0 enabled devices are usually connected with CBCentralManager unboundly. What is bounded and unbounded connection, you can know from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602790/what-is-the-difference-between-bounded-and-unbounded-device?rq=1). 
One BLE 4.0 enabled device can be connected with only one master device thus enhancing secured connectivity. You should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415694/how-can-i-create-a-secured-connection-to-ble-peripheral-through-cbcentralmanager?rq=1).
Whether in foreground of background, if the connection exists, the BLE slave device won't get connected with another app or device.

Comment: The last part is actually partly false. BLE peripherals connected to iOS will connect to multiple apps on the same system. You are correct that they will not connect to another iPhone, iPad, etc. So if you have 2 apps that see your peripheral, they can both connect to it. We had this issue a while back with 2 of our apps controlling the peripheral at the same time while both were running at the same time.